# Update only phone's contact number when multiple number under one Contact

Tags: android, contacts

I have one contact in mobile like name="ABC".**phone** number="123456789" type="work" **google** number="987654321" type="work".Now when i update the contact of number "123456789" at that time first get the id of that contact and then update the contact with phone.type="work".But the problem is that when i update the contact then the contact will be update in both the number like phone number and google number.So how can i update only the phone's contact number but not any other account joined with this id?.I have written the code as below:

```
    public Long getID(String number) {

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(number));
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                return c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
            return null;
        }  
 public int gettype(String number) {

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(number));
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    new String[] { PhoneLookup.TYPE }, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
            return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.TYPE));

            }
            return 0;
        }


Long id = getID(delnumber);
int contact_type= gettype(delnumber);


 String selectPhone = Data.CONTACT_ID+ "=? AND "    + Data.MIMETYPE+ "='"+ Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+ "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=?";
                                                    Log.i("type",""+contact_type);
                                                    if(contact_type==1)
                                                    {String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_HOME)};
                                                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone,phoneArgs).withValue(Phone.NUMBER,getnum).build());}
                                                    else if(contact_type==2)
                                                    {String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};
                                                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone,phoneArgs).withValue(Phone.NUMBER,getnum).build());}
                                                    else if(contact_type==3)
                                                    {String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_WORK)};
                                                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone,phoneArgs).withValue(Phone.NUMBER,getnum).build());}
                                                    else
                                                    {String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};
                                                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone,phoneArgs).withValue(Phone.NUMBER,getnum).build());}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If you found can you post it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all its hard to read you code with the formatting you have above, this maybe why no tried to answer this, but here is the code I use to update a phone number without updating any other phone number:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {userId})
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?", new String[] {phoneId})
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, phoneNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, type)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, label)
            .build());

    try 
    {
        resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
```

The key is to have contact ID of the contact and phone ID of the phone you want to update in your selection for the query.

Comment: can you provide the URI's for getting the contact ID & phone ID of a particular contact?