# Storing multiple contact numbers under same tag

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I was just wondering how are multiple contact numbers stored under same tag in android.

For example, I could store 9876543210 and 9812345670 under the same tag TYPE_HOME or TYPE_MOBILE. But while storing a number programmatically, I could only insert 1 contact on 1 tag and it gets replaced if a second entry is made to it.

Also, How to store multiple numbers under same tag programmatically?

Comment: perhaps here is the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319445/update-only-phones-contact-number-when-multiple-number-under-one-contact

Comment: why you do not concat a special character after every number.

Comment: and then how would i be storing it on my phone. Of course,that would not be what you want to see on your contact list.

Answer (score 0):

Tag is supposed to handle a single value,You could subclass the object and add an array to property and save the values as you need in there

Comment: I did not exactly get you. what do you mean by "subclass the object and add an array to property"?? 
As array's can't be passed in it and only an object can be.